# Inter-thread queue strategy that favors MANY Writers, and a single Reader

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue, locking

Most reading I've done indicates that the various 'lock free' concurrency constructs - eg. ReaderWriterLockSlim with queue, BlockingCollection/ConcurrentQueue - are designed to (or do by implementation) favor readers.

Is there a queue strategy/implementations that both 1) *favors writers* and 2) *minimizes writer context switches*?

It is okay to penalize the reader or to reduce the total-ordering of queued messages. That is, the order of items queued from each individual writer should be maintained, but needs not be consistent with all writers.

I've considered having a different per-writer queues (or multiple queues serving a distinct set of the different writers), but it seems like this particular case would have some focus/support and a common implementation. There are more than a stone worth of writers.

Comment: What about multiple ConcurrentQueue feeding in to a [BlockingCollection<T>.TakeFromAny(](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267247(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Aha! I was just looking for such a method. This would be the [easy] way to use multiple writer queues. It still seems like it'd be about as common to have Wn/1 (writers/consumers) as 1/Cn, which many thing seem 'better suited' for .. or maybe that's simply not the case.

Answer (score 0):

That's looks like a specific case to me and so there won't be any framework implementation present (per I know off). Talking about `BlockingCollection` (it by default uses `ConcurrentQueue<T>`) is a general framework implementation of classic `producer-consumer` problem where by it will block producer thread if queue is full and consumer thread if queue is empty.

Not sure though, what's your specific case and why you want to favor writer thread over reader thread.

Comment: Scenario: [many] writers want to send logging / statistic / diagnostic metrics. They do this by sending the raw data to an aggregator which will leisurely persist the information. This outflow of data should not 'block' or 'steal work' from the operation that is actually occurring.